# How to create NLTK custom stopword file

Tags: python, nltk, stop-words

I have a collection of about 1,200 text files, each about 5,000 words.  Each file is a transcript of a conference calls and contains company names.  I want to be able to process the files to remove company names because they are repeated frequently and therefore not relevant to other processing that I want to do.  To accomplish this, I have attempted to write a script to create a custom set of stop name for company names.  My thought is to create files that are formatted the same as the NLTK stopword lists and can be used  in the same way.

Here is a snippet of the input file (‘stops_Analyst_Companies.txt’) of company names;  'Atlantic Equities LLP','Avon Capital Advisors','Barclays Capital','Bernstein','BGC Partners','BMO Capital Markets U.S.’,  …..there are about 80 names in total.

I then use another script to remove the company names  from the transcript files and I also remove the NLTK English stop words from the transcript files and then pickle the file for subsequent use.  While the NLTK stopwords are successfully removed , the words in the custom stop word file are not removed.
What I am attempting is several steps beyond my limited command of python so suggestions and guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Following  is the script to create the custom stopword files for Analyst Companies;

```
import os, os.path, sys, nltk, re, pprint, pickle
with open('stops_Analyst_Companies.txt','r') as stops_Analyst_Companies:
stops_Analyst_Companies = stops_Analyst_Companies.read()
stops_Analyst_Companies= [w.lower() for w in stops_Analyst_Companies]
stops_Analyst_Companies = str(stops_Analyst_Companies)
outfile = open ('cln_stops_Analyst_Companies.txt', 'w')
outfile.write(stops_Analyst_Companies)
```

here is a snippet from the ‘cln_stps_Analyst_Companies.txt’ file;
["'", 'a', 't', 'l', 'a', 'n', 't', 'i', 'c', ' ', 'e', 'q', 'u', 'i', 't', 'i', 'e', 's', ' ', 'l', 'l', 'p', "'", ',', "'", 'a', 'v', 'o', 'n', ' ', 'c', 'a', 'p', 'i', 't', 'a', 'l', ' ', 'a', 'd', 'v', 'i', 's', 'o', 'r', 's', "'"

here is the script to remove the stop names from the transcript files;

```
import os, os.path, sys, nltk, re, pprint, pickle
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stopset = set(stopwords.words('english'))
with open('TestStopWords_1.txt','r') as fin:
wordtokens=word_tokenize(fin.read())
lowcase= [w.lower() for w in wordtokens]
# Remove NTLK Stopwords
nostops = [w for w in lowcase if not w in stopset]
print ('NLTK Stopset Words Removed')
print (' ')
print (nostops)
print (' ')
with open ('cln_stops_Analyst_Companies.txt', 'r') as cln_stops_Analyst_Companies:
    customstops = cln_stops_Analyst_Companies.read()
nostops = [w for w in nostops if not w in customstops]
print ('Analyst Companies Names Removed')
print (' ')
print (nostops )
nostops = str(nostops)
with open ("nostops.pickle", 'wb') as outfile:
pickle.dump (nostops, outfile)
print (' ')
print (' Pickle File Created')
print (' ')
```

This is snippet from the TestStopWords file;

of,the, a, Analyst Companies,Atlantic Equities LLP,Avon Capital Advisors

and this is a snippet from the ‘nostops.pickle’ file;

€X®'analyst', 'companies', 'atlantic', 'equities', 'llp', 'avon', 'capital', 'advisors',

Comment: Can you format your question properly? because now it's unclear what you're asking with all the wrong formatting of what's an example, and which part is the file and which part is the code. After you format your question properly, we can help you better.

Comment: Hi Alvas, thanks for the guidance, I will edit the format to improve readibility.  I entered the code usng an indentation of 4 spaces and then indented code following 'with' statements an additional 4 spaces.  However the second indent obviously did not appear in the post.  Cheers, BobS